# Get last four words per column in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataset with multiple columns, one of which (`d$leftContext`) contains strings such as:

```
Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer er hier misschien een 
Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het westen te smijten...Die 
Die 
Die 
Als de
```

For each of these I want to return only the last four words. I first wanted to this with regular expressions, but as I'm quite sure this won't work when the string is shorter than four words (as is the case in the latter three cases). Also, my proposed regex won't work when there are any other characters than spacew between the words (as is the case on the second line). See an example of my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/sK9vZ8/2).

```
.*(?=(\b\w+\s){4}$)
```

So, how can I strip off the four last words (*and* everything that's in between them) in R?

For the block presented above, the result would look like (keep the last four words or less if not enough present):

```
er hier misschien een
westen te smijten...Die 
Die 
Die 
Als de
```

Comment: If you need the last 4 words `sapply(strsplit(d1[,1], ' '), tail,4)`

Comment: The first thing to realize is that both regex and R use backslash as escape characters so that you need to double the "\"'s when creating a pattern string using R's wrappers to the system PCRE library.

Comment: @BondedDust I have experience with Regex in JavaScript, and I'm still trying to figure out which characters I'm ought to escape in R... Can't seem to find any list online!

Comment: @BramVanroy Could you update with the expected result to avoid confusion

Comment: @akrun Done. I think your solution would work, only not in the second case. If you 'd change `4` to 1, for instance, the output would be `smijten...Die` instead of just `Die`.

Comment: @BramVanroy Can you check if there is a typo in your expected result as the `first row` seems to be the opposite of what you wanted. i.e. instead of `Eens zien of je`, should it be `er hier misschien een`

Comment: @BramVanroy I think the word definition is not clear, then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that both regex and R use backslash as escape characters so that you need to double the "\"'s when creating a pattern string.  This will return the 4 words and the embedded separations for a list of the character class items `" "`, `","`, and `"."`. The only character to escape is the backslash.

```
> sub( patt='(.+)(([ ,.]+\\w+){4})[ ]?$', repl='\\2', Lines)
[1] " er hier misschien een"   " westen te smijten...Die" "Die "  
[4] "Die "                     "Als de"
```

It's not actually matching the last three, since they do not actually have 4 separator-word patterns. I needed to put in the final "[ ]? because several of the copied lines had trailing spaces that messed up my matching.

```
>dput(Lines)
c("Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer er hier misschien een ", 
"Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het westen te smijten...Die ", 
"Die ", "Die ", "Als de")
```

Comment: Is there any noticeable difference between using `[ ]` and `\\s`?

Comment: Not that I know of, specifically for that comparison anyway. It would be easier to generalize the character class version to allow other text separators such as `"."` and `","` and "/" which I thought you were requesting. The R `?regex`-page says `\\s` in a pattern would be one of: `"tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters."`

Comment: You can find the text-representation that R recognizes for some of the members of the "space'-class at the `?Quotes` help page.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
df <- data.frame(leftContext=c('Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer er hier misschien een','Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het westen te smijten...Die','Die','Die','Als de'), stringsAsFactors=F );
df$leftContext;
## [1] "Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer er hier misschien een"
## [2] "Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het westen te smijten...Die"
## [3] "Die"
## [4] "Die"
## [5] "Als de"
sub('(\\b\\w+\\b\\W*){1,4}$','',df$leftContext);
## [1] "Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer "
## [2] "Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het "
## [3] ""
## [4] ""
## [5] ""
```

The key is the use of the variable bound `{1,4}`; that ensures that if there are fewer than four words, the 1:3 trailing words will still be stripped. Also, non-whitespace separators are easily covered by `\W`, which matches any non-word character.

**Edit:** Sorry, the OP said "return" and then later "strip off", and I took "strip off" to mean remove.

I've been trying to revise my regex to accomplish the requirement, but remarkably, it appears to me that R's regex implementation, at least with regard to expanding capture groups in the replacement string when there is a variable bound in the regex, is broken. It is failing to properly expand `\1`, `\2` etc. in the replacement string under these circumstances.

To work around the problem, I've figured out a hack that uses `substr()` to extract the trailing part of the input strings that you want:

```
df <- data.frame(leftContext=c('Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer er hier misschien een','Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het westen te smijten...Die','Die','Die','Als de'), stringsAsFactors=F );
df$leftContext;
## [1] "Eens zien of je binnen een paar jaar , wanneer er hier misschien een"
## [2] "Ik zou denken van wel , eens deze kerel verdwenen zullen er nog erger aan de macht komen , mensen , crimineel krankzinnig , en fanatiek godsdienstig genoeg om met atoombommen naar het westen te smijten...Die"
## [3] "Die"
## [4] "Die"
## [5] "Als de"
substr(df$leftContext,nchar(sub('(\\b\\w+\\b\\W*){1,4}$','',df$leftContext))+1,nchar(df$leftContext));
## [1] "er hier misschien een"   "westen te smijten...Die" "Die"                     "Die"                     "Als de"
```

Comment: Can you just match all words `\\w+` to array and take the last 1-4 words?

Comment: @MaxZoom That's exactly what bgoldst's regex does, but you can't just "take" it. You have to replace your catch with something. You can't change things around either, becuase lookaheads can't get quantifiers.

Comment: I suspect you needed to escape the backslash in the 'replacement' argument. See my example code.

Comment: @BondedDust, I did escape the backslash when testing the code. I just didn't show the escape in the discussion text in my answer, because I was trying to emphasize the actual text that the regex implementation works with, rather than the raw user input. There definitely seems to be a bug in R's regex implementation. The reason why your regex works is that it doesn't include a variable bound.

Comment: I've only used regex with the R wrappers. In R, this  is a single character: `"\\"`